# Implementing AGILE methodology in ERP?

Tags: agile, project, erp

We have a huge debate in our organisation to use AGILE in ERP projects. Can anyone give an example of a successful implementation as such?

Comment: Lots of good resources here: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=agile+in+large+projects

Comment: It would be more interesting to mention why you (or others) think an agile approach wouldn't be suitable. What will you conclude if I give you an example of success and one example of failure?

Comment: Also please explain if you are integrating an existing ERP or you are building one. Note: SAP is using Scrum internally. http://www.xpdays.de/2007/downloads/Christian%20Schmidkonz,%20Henrik%20Stotz%20-%20Scrum%20bei%20SAP.pdf

Comment: Concerning ERPs, the most important aspect is that ERPs are huge and development will never be finished.
The best argument of agile development in this context would be: Start small, make little steps (iterations) forward, don't plan big modules through independently.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some papers and websites that you might be interested in:

- [Agile Project Management Methods for ERP: How to Apply Agile Processes to Complex COTS Projects and Live to Tell About It](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.13.1893)
- [Agile ERP: "You don't know what you've got 'till it's gone!" (Requires IEEE Xplore Subscription or article purchase to view)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4293562%2F4293563%2F04293587.pdf%3Farnumber%3D4293587&authDecision=-203)
- [Agile Project Management Methods for ERP](http://www.slideshare.net/lisa_yogi/agile-project-management-methods-of-erp)
- [Agile ERP](http://www.information-age.com/channels/development-and-integration/features/271966/agile-erp.thtml)

I'm not that familiar with building ERP software, but from what it seems, they appear to have a few things in common. ERP software is large in terms of features and scope and development often takes a long time. I believe that Agile principles might be of value here, even if you aren't using full-blown agile methodologies.

The central tenets of Agile are rapid delivery of working software, accepting late-changing requirements, and close cooperation between the business and users and developers. A highly iterative approach to building an ERP system and close collaboration between the users and the developers to continually add the features that add the most value seem like it will yield the most bang for your buck.